# pymssql: remove or replace NULL values from result rows

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I have been having a recurring problem when I perform MSSQL queries using pymssql.

This is the code I'm using:

```
listOfRows = [] # I will append all reult rows to this list

conn = pymssql.connect(user = 'the user', password = 'password', server = 'theserver', database = 'thedb')
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = 'SELECT * FROM table'

cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    listOfRows.append(row)
```

The listOfRows list ends up as a list tuples such as:

```
[('value1', None, 'valuex'), (None, 'value2', 'valuex'), None]
```

Notice that the tuples have None values, but also the list always end up with its last value also being None.

Many operations I try to do with these results give me an error. For example:

```
[list(x) for x in listOfRows]
```

results in the error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Is there an efficient way to avoid this problem? The solution can be either at the query-level or with a Python method. I find myself spending a lot of time writing for loops in order to remove None values.

Comment: If `listOfRows` is indeed `[('value1', None, 'valuex'), (None, 'value2', 'valuex')]`, you would not get this error. There's something more going on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have messed up the logic in your `while` loop. Currently you fetch the row from DB, append it to the list and then make a check whether the row was not `None`. Due to this, you are having entry as `None` at the end of your list:

```
[('value1', None, 'valuex'), (None, 'value2', 'valuex'), None]
#                                   single `None` object  ^
```

Instead, you should fetch the row from DB, check for `None` and then append it to list. Hence your code should be:

```
cursor.execute(query)
row = cursor.fetchone()
while row:
    listOfRows.append(row)     # <- Interchanged
    row = cursor.fetchone()    # <-- Lines
```

Also, in your current logic you were skipping the content of first row.